# How to redirect IO to the windows console in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

When I press "Run" my code is running in the IDE built-in terminal:
[image]

How can I debug my python console application in windows terminal using PyCharm?

Comment: Why not just use PyCharm's inbuilt debugger?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you can debug using the pycharm debugger:

[image]

And that will open up the debugger. You can set breakpoints like so:

You can set breakpoints be clicking on the side:

[image]

And the debugger window will pop up:

[image]